# How to edit mail.php user interface

Tags: email, cakephp, config

I need a help.
i want user interface for mail(smtp).php in CakePHP

If any one Knows help me....

```
public $stmp = array(
    'transport' => 'Mail',
    'from' => 'you@localhost',
);

public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('contact@media.com' => 'Admin'),
    'host' => 'mail.mediaenter code here.com',
    'port' => 25,
    'timeout' => 60,
    'username' => '[EMAIL]',
    'password' => '[PASSWORD]',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => true,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost you need to Ensure your configuration is all set. Here is a working configuration:

in config/app.php

`'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Smtp',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'your host',
            'port' => your post,
            'timeout' => 60,
            'username' => 'your username',
            'password' => 'your password',
            'transport' => 'Smpt',
            'tls' => true
        ],
    ]`

Then you need to create your own interface. A standard CakePHP view, would be most appropriate if you make an HTML form.

In the controller of where your HTML data is being sent, ideally as 'post'method, you can use the following code to proceed:

Before the controllers class declaration:

```
use Cake\Network\Email\Email;
```

Then in your action:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) { //Assuming you used POST method
    $postData = $this->request->data; //Getting HTML form fields values.
    try {
          $email = new Email();
          $email->profile('default');
          $email->from(['from@email.com' => 'from Name.')
                   ->to('to@email.com')
                   ->replyTo('replyto@email.com')
                   ->subject('your subject')
                   ->send('Your message here!');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
     echo 'Exception : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
```

With the code above here, if for some reason the email is not sent you an error is being echoed in the catch statement.

For further configuration options [click here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html)